# How can I change the size of QChart?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning about charts and I decided use Qt to practice. However, I'm trying to change the size of a Qchart unsuccessfully. I nested a Qchart inside of a QVboxLayout & I tried to change the size of both the QChart and QVBoxLayout with minimumSize() fuction but not was any change, also I tried with resize() function but the result was the same. Whitch is the way to change the size of a Qchart? 
PD: I'm using a default QChart example.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the size of a Chart?